# R for-loop vs Python for-loop Performance

Tags: python, r, performance, for-loop

There already is some discussion on this topic but they don't quite address my question. Sorry in advance if they do and I didn't realize.

Here are two simple for-loop setups in R and python -

R for-loop (took 3.41s on my computer):

```
datafr  <- matrix(0,nrow=24*365,ncol=15)
matrix3d  <- array(0,dim=c(24*365,12,7))

#================
start_time <- Sys.time()
for (p in 1:150) {
  for (m in 1:2) {
    l  <- rep(0.7*runif(365),each=24)
    a  <- rep(0.7*runif(365),each=24)
    pp <- 1+floor(15*runif(7))
    for (j in 1:7) {
      bun     <- datafr[,pp[j]]*a
      for (h in 2:(24*365)) {
        matrix3d[h,m,j] <- matrix3d[h-1,m,j]*l[h] + bun[h]
      }  
    }
  }
}
Sys.time() - start_time
#================
#took 3.41s on my computer
```

And here's the same code in Python (#took 17.87s on my computer):

```
import numpy as np
import time
import pandas as pd

datafr= pd.DataFrame(0, index=range(24*365),columns=range(15))
matrix3d = np.zeros((24*365,12,7))

#=============
start_time = time.time()
for p in range(150):
    for m in range(2):
        l = np.repeat(0.7*np.random.random(365),24)
        a = np.repeat(0.7*np.random.random(365),24)
        pp = 1+np.floor(15*np.random.random(7))
        for j in range(7):
            bun = np.asarray(datafr.iloc[:,int(pp[j])-1],dtype=np.float32)*a
            for h in range(1,(24*365)):
                matrix3d[h,m,j] = matrix3d[h-1,m,j]*l[h]+bun[h] #bottleneck
round(time.time() - start_time,2)
#================
#took 17.87s on my computer
```

R is over 5 times faster than Python. Is this to be expected? I saw that Python's for-loop is faster than R's, unless you use R's lapply in which case R beats Python if the number of steps is greater than 1000 (https://datascienceplus.com/loops-in-r-and-python-who-is-faster/), but that is not what I see here (I'm not using lapply). Can the Python script be improved in a way that doesn't use decorators or magic functions or generators etc? I'm simply curious. Thanks

Comment: In general you should expect them to at about the same pace. It is a common misconception often showcased with code that is not exactly equivalent for Python and R. Heck, you should expect `for-loop`s to be faster than `lapply` unless done poorly as `*apply` functions just create the loop for you and adds overhead for their general use.

Comment: The reference actually is a brilliant example of the misconception. In the comments of the reference I showed a crucial error in the showcase a few months back. Here illustrating that the `lapply` code is not equivalent to the `for-loop` making it much faster due to it performing a different (and wrong) task.

Comment: I know what you mean. In my code above I tried removing the last for-loop and did `matrix3d[1:8760,m,j] = matrix3d[0:8759,m,j]*l[1:8760]+bun[1:8760]`. It run in under a second. Turns out this type of vectorization (to make things simpler, say to add 1 to the previous number and replace, starting from the second number) turns e.g. [2,1,4,6,3] to [2,3,2,5,7] (rightly so) instead of turning [2,1,4,6,3] to [2,3,4,5,6] like the for-loop does. Also making this change in the R code I was able to run it in under a second too. That said I think the R and Python code above are equivalent.

Comment: 1) Actually that is not exactly what i was talking about. Vectorization will greatly increase your speed, as the functions are often implemented in `c`, `c++` or `fortran`, but here i simply talk about the code prior to vectorization. A `for-loop` is still faster. As to whether the two pieces of code are equivalent is a question that is much harder to state.

Comment: 2) As for equivalency, i don't know exactly why the Python code runs slower, and I'm not expert in Python by any stretch. But looking i quickly spot a few 'non-equivalencies.' In R you are using `array` and `matrix` which are much faster for subsetting compared to a standard `data.frame`.  In Python you are using a `pandas` data.frame, and converting it to a numpy `array` (equivalent to a R matrix). This conversion is not equivalent and would add overhead. To my knowledge numpy is usualy known for fast matrix operations, i don't know if it is also known for fast subsets.

Comment: R and Python store matrix-like data in column-major / row-major fashion. The speed gap could be due to cache misses.

Answer (score 3):

R loops used to be slow during 2014 or 15. They aren't slow anymore software's and programming language evolve over time and things are never true forever. JS is a perfect example of this.

R for loops are not slow and you can use them anytime you want however the garbage collector of R is slow and you shouldn't grow a vector inside a loop which copies it multiple time. If you avoid that part you are almost always in safe hands

And you could also try set method from data.table if you need more speed from loop or parallelize it